# Give a Specific Part of a Text Component Colour

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have some text with a border as such.

[image]

However, I want to achieve something like this, where the top bit has an orange colour and there are icons, how do I do so?

[image]

Code:

```
<div>
   <p style="font-family: 'Space Grotesk'; margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 230px; border: 2px solid black; width: 250px; padding-left: 20px; height: 280px; padding-top: 40px; border-radius: 10px;">Awesome product! Works well. Easy to wear, great color scheme, does not tear easily and came home in under two days. Worth every rupee, it really helped me save money from  buying the one-time use patches and rubber patches and has been a great experience with the patch.</p>
   <hr style="height: 2px; background-color: black; margin-top: -314px; width: 270px; margin-left: 232px; border: none; position: relative;">
   <h3 style="font-family: 'Space Grotesk'; margin-top: 230px; margin-left: 350px;">Rishan Reddy</h3>
   <h3 style="font-family: 'Space Grotesk'; margin-left: 420px; margin-top: -12px;">Indus</h3>
</div>
```

Also, I want to make three of these divs side by side. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I just added it. Check the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fontawesome for your ellipsis. The header and content can be done as two divs in a container as below. It should be self-explanatory however if not, drop me a comment and I'll elaborate

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 30ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height:10rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: #FFBF23;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.content {
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
}

.signature-container {
  margin-top:0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.review-container {
display:grid;
gap:1rem;
grid-template-columns:repeat(3, fit-content(30ch));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class='review-container'>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>This is Review 1</p>
    <div class='signature-container'>
      <div>
        <p>Adam Silver</p>
        <p>Ashburn</p>
        <p>Virginia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>This is Review 2</p>
    <div class='signature-container'>
      <div>
        <p>Adam Silver</p>
        <p>Ashburn</p>
        <p>Virginia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>This is Review 3</p>
    <div class='signature-container'>
      <div>
        <p>Adam Silver</p>
        <p>Ashburn</p>
        <p>Virginia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>This is Review 4</p>
    <div class='signature-container'>
      <div>
        <p>Adam Silver</p>
        <p>Ashburn</p>
        <p>Virginia</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I use margin-top with this? Like how do I move the entire thing a little down?

Comment: Never mind, I got that. But, now, how do I put three such of these reviews back to back, like one on the left, one on the middle, and one on the right.

Comment: I've added a class called review-container that uses css grid to position 3 reviews side by side. If you add a 4th then that appears on the next line, etc.